# Make the last TextBox in a DataTemplate Stretch

Tags: wpf, datatemplate

I have an ItemsControl:

```
<Border Grid.Row="1" Margin="20" BorderBrush="AliceBlue" BorderThickness="1" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
   <ItemsControl Margin="10" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" ItemsSource="{Binding SelectedEventHistoryEntryCollection}" ItemTemplateSelector="{StaticResource computerEventHistoryDataTemplateSelector}"/>
</Border>
```

With some datatemplates. I'm testing the first template:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="DetailsDataTemplate">
        <Grid>
            <Label Width="150" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Content="{x:Static resx:Resources.Label_ServiceDept}"/>
            <TextBox Margin="110,0,0,0" Width="200" IsReadOnly="True" Text="{Binding ServiceDepartment}" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>

            <Label Width="150" Margin="0,40,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Content="{x:Static resx:Resources.Label_SLA}"/>
            <TextBox Margin="110,40,0,0" Width="200" IsReadOnly="True" Text="{Binding SLA}" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>

            <Label Width="150" Margin="0,80,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Content="{x:Static resx:Resources.Label_Details}"/>
            <TextBox Margin="110,80,10,10" IsReadOnly="True" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding Details}"/>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
```

I would like the last Textbox in the datatemplate to use up the remaining space, but nothing I tried works. How can I get this uncooperateive TextBox to stretch?

**Edit:** Removed the Height Property on the Textbox.

Comment: The strong point of a Grid is that it has columns and rows, which you do not use at all, did you create that with auto-alignment in a designer or something? (Also: Don't trust people who recommend DockPanels over Grids!)

Comment: When you say stretch, do you mean that you want it to expand to take up the remainder of the vertical and horizontal space in the lower right-hand side of the available display area?

Comment: @John Laffoon - Yes that is exactly what I want.

Comment: @H.B. - I just used the Grid as a container. I can add the columns and rows if it will help.

Comment: I just updated my answer to include a sample showing the usage of the star sizing with the grid.  I made a few assumptions on your formatting, but that should get you most of the way there.

Comment: Could you post a mocked up screenshot of what you're hoping to achieve? This will get you close. A few tweaks should get you the rest of the way. I'm guessing that you're aiming for a scrollable list of your history event objects where the details field dynamically sizes as needed. If that's the case, you're close.

Comment: Ok, here is the link: http://i.imgur.com/bkwIc.jpg The last textbox on the bottom is what I want to take up the remaining space. In the pic the Height is hard-coded. If I remove the height attribute it will size according to its contents, unless the Grid (your code) is not contained in the DataTemplate.

Comment: So, the ItemsControl your binding to is populating the DataGrid.  And, the Status and Detailed Description fields are just additional information for the selected row in the DataGrid. Right?

Comment: Updated answer with another approach.  This is definitely doable, but it may take a little tweaking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was a little slow on the uptake with my first answer.  After realizing what you were after I don't think that approach was correct.  Also, I don't think you can easily achieve what you're after using DataTemplates.  However, I do think you have a few options:

1. Check into [Prism](http://compositewpf.codeplex.com/) since is is good at doing things like building composite applications.  However, it seems like WAY overkill for this problem.  So, a more direct approach may be...
2. Build out custom controls for each separate detail view you have and then write some custom logic to load each view as needed.  You would set it up like this...

You main grid and your details view host (i.e. the ContentControl) would be set up something like this:

```
<Grid Background="Transparent">

    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="1*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="8" />
        <RowDefinition Height="1.5*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <DataGrid Grid.Row="0" />

    <GridSplitter Grid.Row="1" Background="Transparent"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"  />

    <Border Grid.Row="2" BorderBrush="DarkGray" BorderThickness="1" CornerRadius="3" Padding="8">
        <ContentControl Grid.Row="2" x:Name="myContent" />            
    </Border>

</Grid>
```

And each of your custom controls for your individual detail views would be set up something like this:

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfApplication1.CustomUserControl"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Content="Status" />
        <Label Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Content="Description" />

        <TextBox Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Status}" />
        <TextBox Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding Description}" />

    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

At run time a row is selected in your DataGrid, you would have to load the correct user control with some code like this:

```
myContent.Content = new CustomUserControl();
```

Each of your custom controls would have to use star sizing, etc. to get the layouts to look right - which is what you were after with your question.  Obviously there is still a lot of wireup that would need to be done.

That should give you what you are after.  Sorry for the run-around on the first answer!

Comment: Thanks, you've been a great help.

Answer (score 2):

Change the grid to a `DockPanel` with `LastChildFill="true"`.
You can then get rid of all of the `Margin`s and let WPF do the layout automatically.

Comment: If I change it to a `DockPanel` then it becomes too big and scroll bars appear. The `Border` shown in the code above is inside a grid, don't know if that has anything to do with it.

Answer (score 2):

Use a `<DockPanel>` instead of a `<Grid>`.

The last item in the `DockPanel` uses remaining space.

Answer (score 2):

Generally, I use `<Grid.RowDefinitions>` and `<Grid.ColumnDefinitions>` in conjunction with star sizing * instead of margins for this type of layout.

**UPDATE 1:** (Removed for clarity)

**UPDATE 2:**  When I wind up in situations like this where I can’t figure out where to apply a binding or a template I try to back up and look at the problem differently.  I almost always take it back to the MVVM pattern.  In this case, your Model is your EventHistory object.  Your ViewModel has an `ObservableCollection<EventHistory>`.  And your View is simply binding to that collection.  So, to get something like this:

[image]

You would use something like this for your View:

```
<Grid>

    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="1*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="8" />
        <RowDefinition Height="1.5*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <DataGrid Grid.Row="0" AutoGenerateColumns="True" 
                ItemsSource="{Binding}" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" 
                HorizontalGridLinesBrush="DarkGray" VerticalGridLinesBrush="DarkGray" />

    <GridSplitter Grid.Row="1" 
                    Background="Transparent"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"   />

    <Border Grid.Row="2" BorderBrush="DarkGray" BorderThickness="1" CornerRadius="3" Padding="8">

        <Grid>

            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Content="Status" />
            <TextBox Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Margin="0,0,0,8" Text="{Binding Path=Status}" />

            <Label Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Content="Detailed Description" />
            <TextBox Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Path=Description}" />

        </Grid>
    </Border>
</Grid>
```

And that is just fine -- because that is what you are trying to achieve.  The bindings on the 2 labels and textboxes at the bottom of the screen don’t have to be part of any data template.  They are part of the view (everything inside the red border in the screenshot).  All of the resizing works and everything is good.  If you really want to move things into a DataTemplate, it is probably possible, but this seemed more natural at this point.

NOTE:  After creating the View (area inside the red border) I hosted it in the main window leaving an area to the right as per  your screenshot.  I also took a few liberties with a grid splitter, star resizing and margins so things would take up all of the available space while maintaining the pictured proportions.

Hopefully that helps!

Comment: I'll take another look at this next week... time to go for the weekend. Thanks for the info so far.

Comment: This works fine if the controls are not used with the ItemsControl and datatemplate. I guess I'm stuck with a hard coded size for now.

Comment: Could you post a mocked up screenshot of what you're hoping to achieve?  This will get you close.  A few tweaks should get you the rest of the way.  I'm guessing that you're aiming for a scrollable list of your history event objects where the details field dynamically sizes as needed.  If that's the case, you're close.

Comment: Sorry I should have clarified the use of the Datatemplates, my fault. Based on which Item is selected in the DataGrid a different 'view' of data is displayed below the datagrid. The image link I provided is for just one system. Now if the user selects an item that belongs to a different system there will be a different set of textboxes, labels, etc. below the Datagrid. Sorry again. And thanks so much for your perserverance on this :)

Comment: Ok, I'm with you now.  Yeah, this approach really isn't what you're after.  I've got one other thing in mind.  I'll post it as a separate answer.  Thanks!